# Angularjs ticker throwing error as shift() is not a function

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to ticker in AngularJs, I am getting error as

> `shift()` is not a function

Please suggest.

```
$scope.boxes = [];
$scope.moving = false;

$scope.moveLeft = function() {
  $scope.moving = true;
  $timeout($scope.switchFirst, 1000);
};
$scope.switchFirst = function() {
  $scope.boxes.push($scope.boxes.shift());
  $scope.moving = false;
  $scope.$apply();
};

$interval($scope.moveLeft, 2000);
```

### Update

The following is my controller code

```
$scope.memoryMap = [];
$scope.loading = true;
myService.getInfo(function(metrics) {
  if (metrics) {
    $scope.memoryMap = metrics.memoryMap;
  }
});

$scope.moving = false;
$scope.moveLeft = function() {
  $scope.moving = true;
  $timeout($scope.switchFirst, 1000);
};
$scope.switchFirst = function() {
  $scope.memoryMap.push($scope.memoryMap.splice(0, 1)[0]);
  $scope.moving = false;
  $scope.$apply();
};

$interval($scope.moveLeft, 2000);
```

Comment: can share full controller function?

Comment: your variable `$scope.boxes` changes from an array to something else (a number maybe) somewhere in your controller. You need to provide more code where that variable is used

Comment: I have updated the code, please suggest.

Comment: console (metrics.memoryMap) and see what are you getting, I think this is creating problem?

Comment: Thanks Rahul, I have converted object into Array. Its worked fine.